# insert a data at empty line and again create a new empty line in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

Below is the data in the file

```
  [dev01]
  server7.srv.us.domain.net
  server3.srv.us.domain.net
  server2.srv.us.domain.net
  server1.srv.us.domain.net
  
  [dev02
  server5.srv.us.domain.net
```

I need to grep for dev01 part and insert the new server details(server9.srv.us.domain.net) after line server1.srv.us.domain.net and again insert an empty line using shell script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk -v tag="[dev01]" -v servline="server1.srv.us.domain.net" -v addline="server9.srv.us.domain.net" '$0 ~ tag { found=1 } found==1 && $0 ~ servline { $0=$0"\n  "addline;found=0 }1' file > file.tmp && mv -f file.tmp file
```

Explanation:

```
awk -v tag="[dev01]" -v servline="server1.srv.us.domain.net" -v addline="server9.srv.us.domain.net" 

# Pass tag section to edit as tag, line to insert after a servline and actual line to insert as addline

   '$0 ~ tag { 
               found=1       # If line ($0) pattern matches to tag, set found to 1
             } 
    found==1 && $0 ~ servline { 
               $0=$0"\n  "addline;  # If found equal 1 and the current line is equal to servline, add a new line and the variable addline to the existing line
               found=0              # Reset the found marker
             }1' file > file.tmp && mv -f file.tmp file 

# Redirect output to temp file and move temp to original to commit the changes
```

If you have recent version of GNU awk, you don't need to do this and can use awk -i

Using sed:

```
sed '/\[dev01\]/,/\[/{s/server1.srv.us.domain.net/server1.srv.us.domain.net\n  server9.srv.us.domain.net/}' file
```

Search for lines from [dev01] to any lines with "[" and process. Substitute "server1.srv.us.domain.net" with "server1.srv.us.domain.net", a new line and "server9.srv.us.domain.net" Commit to the file with -i

Comment: THanks Raman, Command works, Could you please explain more on the commands by breaking to shorter ones

Comment: I've broken the solution down as requested.

Comment: If the solution meets you needs, please take the time to up vote and accept the solution.